# Write own Wrapper-class that allows Ints, Floats and Strings

Tags: scala, types, wrapper

On startup I'm reading in a .xml-file and want to store the data in an Object at runtime.

The thing is, I do not want to manually specify every field, but use a Map to store the different values.

But instead of using "String" or a .xml-class like "Node" or something the like I'd like my Map to be of type:

Map[StringKey, Wrapper] where Wrapper can hold **either** an Int, a Float or a String.

Now something like

```
class Wrapper(val: AnyVal)
{
  def this(val: String) = this(val)
  def this(val: Int) = this(val)
  def this(val: Float) = this(val)
}
```

Is not really what I want. I'd like to be 100% sure that it's either a String, an Int or a Float.

I could write an empty constructor and setter-methods instead, but that's ugly.

Another option would be to cast everything to String -> not what I want.

Whenever I retrieve/get a value from the Map I'd like it to manually convert to its type. Like if it's an Int there, something like:

```
val size = cache.get("size").actualType
```

should automatically be an Int (that is, if the Wrapper with key "size" held an Int).

Is there anything ready to use, or can I somehow smartly use Enumeration for the task?

Maybe there is a better solution, like some FP-concept I'm not used to (although this seems to be the domain of OOP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Scala is statically typed, even though it has lots of useful type inference. It needs to set the type of `val size` at compile-time.

In the following possible solution, the type of `val values` is `List[Any]`, since `Any` is the common parent for all the possible return types from the `case` clauses:

```
trait Wrapper

case class IntWrapper(value: Int) extends Wrapper

case class StringWrapper(value: String) extends Wrapper

case class DoubleWrapper(value: Double) extends Wrapper

val wrappers = List(
  IntWrapper(1),
  StringWrapper("1"),
  DoubleWrapper(1.0d)
)

val values = wrappers.map{
  case IntWrapper(v) => v
  case StringWrapper(v) => v
  case DoubleWrapper(v) => v
}
```

In the context of your code, what are you planning to do with the variable `size`, given that you don't know its type?

Comment: Your last question is absolutely right... coming to think of, I should probably just store every value as String as well and cast it as needed, as I do not have information beforehand an automatic conversion wouldn't be really helpful.